# How to change the thread of redo logfile group in standby database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard

Is there some way to correct the thread of redo logfile group? it's ok the thread to be wrong?

executing the following query I get de logfile groups, thread and members:

```
set linesize 2000;
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
col member for a80;
select * from (
select g.THREAD#,g.group#,m.type,m.member,g.bytes/1024/1024 "LOGGROUP_SIZE_MB",g.status,nvl(m.status,'FILE IS IN USE') as status_file from 
v$log g inner join v$logfile m on m.group#=g.group# 
union all
select g.THREAD#,g.group#,m.type,m.member,g.bytes/1024/1024 "LOGGROUP_SIZE_MB",g.status,nvl(m.status,'FILE IS IN USE') as status_file from 
v$standby_log g inner join v$logfile m on m.group#=g.group#)
order by type,THREAD#,group#
/

   THREAD#     GROUP# TYPE    MEMBER                                                                           LOGGROUP_SIZE_MB STATUS           STATUS_FILE
---------- ---------- ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- --------------
         1          1 ONLINE  +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_1.276.1052413891                                                50 CLEARING         FILE IS IN USE
         1          1 ONLINE  +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_1.264.1052413893                                                  50 CLEARING         FILE IS IN USE
         1          2 ONLINE  +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_2.277.1052413931                                                50 CURRENT          FILE IS IN USE
         1          2 ONLINE  +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_2.265.1052413933                                                  50 CURRENT          FILE IS IN USE
         2          3 ONLINE  +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_3.278.1052413939                                                50 UNUSED           FILE IS IN USE
         2          3 ONLINE  +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_3.266.1052413941                                                  50 UNUSED           FILE IS IN USE
         2          4 ONLINE  +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_4.279.1052413947                                                50 UNUSED           FILE IS IN USE
         2          4 ONLINE  +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_4.267.1052413947                                                  50 UNUSED           FILE IS IN USE
         1          5 STANDBY +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_5.280.1052413961                                                50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
         1          5 STANDBY +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_5.268.1052413963                                                  50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
         1          6 STANDBY +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_6.281.1052413969                                                50 ACTIVE           FILE IS IN USE
         1          6 STANDBY +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_6.269.1052413969                                                  50 ACTIVE           FILE IS IN USE
         2          7 STANDBY +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_7.282.1052413975                                                50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
         2          7 STANDBY +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_7.270.1052413975                                                  50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
         2          8 STANDBY +FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_8.271.1052413983                                                  50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
         2          8 STANDBY +DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_8.283.1052413981                                                50 UNASSIGNED       FILE IS IN USE
```

You can see that I have some logfile groups with thread 1 and 2. This happen because I've duplicated this database from RAC environment.

My current thread in this environment (physical standby) is 0:

```
SQL> show parameters thread
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer     2
thread                               integer     0
```

How can I change the thread of all redo logfile groups to 0 as well? I've tried to drop each and recreate, but this is not possible, for example, I need to switchlog the online logfile group 1 to drop, but the database is not open because is a standby:

```
SQL> alter database drop logfile group 1;
alter database drop logfile group 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01624: log 1 needed for crash recovery of instance imootstb (thread 1)
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '+DADOS/mootstb/onlinelog/group_1.276.1052413891'
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '+FRA/mootstb/onlinelog/group_1.264.1052413893'

SQL> alter system switch logfile;
alter system switch logfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open
```

If it is not possible, it's ok the thread keep wrong? or will have some strange behavior in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with not having the `thread` parameter explicitly set in a single instance environment.

```
SQL> show parameter thread

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
ofs_threads                          integer     4
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer     1
thread                               integer     0
threaded_execution                   boolean     FALSE
SQL> select thread# from v$instance;

   THREAD#
----------
         1

SQL>
```

By the way, you can not add a logfile to thread 0:

```
SQL> select thread#, group# from v$log;

   THREAD#     GROUP#
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3

SQL> alter database add logfile thread 0 ('/oradata/redo0.log') size 100M;

Database altered.

SQL> alter database add logfile thread 2 ('/oradata/redo2.log') size 100M;

Database altered.

SQL> select thread#, group# from v$log;

   THREAD#     GROUP#
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         2          5

SQL>
```